# Making two methods interact in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, simpy

I am trying to create a simple simulation. There is a class Hunter that hunts deer. I have given the hunter a likelihood of scoring a hit and the deer a likelihood of dodging a hit.

I first introduce the libraries and some values that I will use throughout the script:

```
import random
import simpy
import numpy as np

DEER = 40
DISTANCE = 100
EVASION_CHANCE = 0.85
HIT_CHANCE = 0.60
SIM_TIME = 100

deer_hunted = 0
```

Then I define the Hunter class:

```
class Hunter:
    def __innit__(self, env, deer, evasion_chance):
        self.env = env
        self.game= simpy.Resource(env, deer)
        self.evasion_chance = evasion_chance

    def attack(self, env, hunter, hit_chance):
        random_time = max(1, np.random.normal(self.evasion_chance, 0.60))
        yield self.env.timeout(random_time)
        self.env = env
        self.sam = simpy.Resource(env, hunter)
        self.hit_chance = hit_chance
```

Then the scenario or action:

```
def scenario(env, engagement):
    global deer_hunted
    print(f"deer enters the zone.")
    with engagement.deer() as request:
        yield request
        print(f"deer enters danger zone.")
        yield env.process(engagement.attack)
        print(f"deer has been hit")
        deer_downed += 1
```

And then the simulation instructions:

```
def setup(env, deer, evasion_chance, hit_chance):
    engagement = Hunter(env, deer, evasion_chance, hit_chance)

    for i in range(1 , 5):
        env.process(engagement(env, i, engagement))

        while True:
            yield env.timeout(random.randint(hit_chance -1, hit_chance +1))
            i += 1
            env.process(engagement(env, deer, engagement))

print("Starting Simulation")
env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(setup(env, deer_hunted, EVASION_CHANCE, HIT_CHANCE))
env.run(until1=SIM_TIME)

print("Deer Hunted: " +str(deer_hunted))
```

I am looking at how the hunter fared against the 40 deer defined earlier given the accuracy and miss chance. I would like to also integrate distance at a later point but before I could do that, I need to get this script to work on its own. Despite there not being any signals on my screen that the syntax is wrong, I am getting a syntax error on VS Code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error

Comment: invalid syntax.

Comment: Show the full error when you post on here

Comment: post the full error and traceback

Comment: where do you call scenario?

Comment: where are the parameters in your yield env.process(engagement.attack) in scenario

Comment: why do you need env, and hunter in def attack(self, env, hunter, hit_chance)

env got set in you __init__, self is your hunter so hunter is not needed

Comment: so many little things

Answer (score 0):

Likely it could just be the misspelling of `__init__()` which is messing you up.

i.e. this

```
class Hunter:
    def __innit__(self, env, deer, evasion_chance):
        self.env = env
        self.game= simpy.Resource(env, deer)
        self.evasion_chance = evasion_chance
```

should be this:

```
class Hunter:
    def __init__(self, env, deer, evasion_chance):
        self.env = env
        self.game= simpy.Resource(env, deer)
        self.evasion_chance = evasion_chance
```